# How to create pojo classes for json object that have integer keys?

Tags: java, json, android, gson

I want to convert this json request to pojo:

```
{
"query": {
    "pages": {
        "101": {
            "id": 101,
            "title": "My book",
            "index": 1,
            "img": "xyz.com"
        },
        "102": {
            "id": 102,
            "title": "My book",
            "index": 1,
            "img": "xyz.com"
        }

    }
}
}
```

Json object inside pages object contains integer key and they are dynamic, i mean their key can be changed to other integer values. I used json [www.jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) tool to create pojo classes but that doesn't solve my purpose because it will create two separate classes for object 101, 102 and these object can change their key's value. My Point is when I hit the api next time it will come like 104, 105 and so on. So please help me with this.

Comment: Well, why you don't create POJO classes manually?

Comment: Does it make any difference?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can create you custom POJO classes and your custom converter from JSON to POJO

Comment: Thanks, Can you give me some idea about how should I create pojo classes for above json?

Comment: Which library are you using for parsing?

Comment: did you check this answer I think this is some what similar to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47626858/json-with-dynamic-keys-while-using-retrofit-in-android

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the same question

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
// Pojo class
public class Page{
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String img;
    private Integer index;

    public Integer getId(){return id;}
    public void setId(Integer id){this.id = id;}

    public String getTitle(){return title;}
    public void setTitle(String title){this.title = title;}

    public String getImg(){return img;}
    public void setImg(String img){this.img = img;}    

    public Integer getIndex(){return index;}
    public void setIndex(Integer index){this.index = index;}
}
```

if you nedded wrapper class

```
public class Pages{
    List<Page> pages = new List<Page>();

    // add

    // remove

    // etc  
}
```

Json convertion with Jackson

```
List<Page> pages = mapper.readValue(jsonString, ypeFactory.collectionType(List.class, Page.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and best way to do so is to use this website ***http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/***

***Why is it that easy?***

You only have to paste the json schema to the website, and it will generate the required model classes. I have been using it for a long time, and never ever have I got a wrong modal class. It do have lots of features too.

[image]

***Use third party tools for improving your productivity.***

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but did you try to generate pojo using above json?, This will not produce correct pojo class. Also I've mentioned this in my question too.

Comment: I generated it, and it did generate the correct one.

Comment: can you give me that link of generated pojo, from my side it generates separate classes for 101 and 102

Comment: Ya it do, you need separate pojo classes for 101, and 102. Or you can have inner classes, but usually this method is the best. Reduces the number of codes in a single class and makes modal classes easy to identify.

Comment: but 101,102 is not static it will change dynamically in next request, how can I handle this. BTW I am using GSON for parsing.

Comment: Well you have  to have a standard for json keys, or you can have separate model classes for each set of keys. Try to use some schema/format for json.